# Координаты рядом с курсором не исчезают при переходе на другой блок

Tags: карты, координаты, курсор

Вывел координаты рядом с курсором на карте, но при переходе на другой блок они не исчезают а замораживаются в последнем значении, как их убрать, помоги подправить код https://jsfiddle.net/1mr63jyt/1/

```
ymaps.ready().then(function () {
    var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.75, 37.62],
        zoom: 14,
        controls: []
    });


    map.cursors.push('crosshair');

    map.events.add('mousemove', function (e) {
    var coords = e.get('coords');
  
  
$(BL).text([coords[0].toPrecision(7), coords[1].toPrecision(7)].join('\n')); 
});

 
$(function() {
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    var iconPosition = {
      top: e.pageY + 12,
      left: e.pageX + 12
    };
    $('.cursor-icon').offset(iconPosition);
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам следует сделать прослушку по `mouseleave`:

```
 map.events.add("mouseleave", function () {
        $("#BL").text(""); // Очищаем текст при выходе курсора с карты
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогли немного по другому, но получилось отлично https://jsfiddle.net/1nt70q8j/14/

```
map.cursors.push('crosshair');

var $BL = $('#BL');
var cursorRectangle;

map.events.add('mousemove', function (e) {
    var coords = e.get('coords');
    $BL.text([coords[0].toPrecision(7), coords[1].toPrecision(7)].join('\n'));

    // Обновление прямоугольника на карте
    if (cursorRectangle) {
        cursorRectangle.geometry.setCoordinates([coords, [coords[0] + 0.000001, coords[1] + 0.000001]]);
    } else {
        cursorRectangle = new ymaps.Rectangle([coords, [coords[0] + 0.000001, coords[1] + 0.000001]], {}, { visible: false });
        map.geoObjects.add(cursorRectangle);
    }
});

$('#map').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $BL.show();  // Показываем блок с координатами при входе курсора в пределы карты
});
```